# run loop with gnu parallel and pass in a variable

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I need to run a bash function for each element in a dir via gnu parallel. I need to access a evn variable for this function. how do I pass in it. for example following code in a shell script. I have a variable DIRS=/folder/log. how do I pass 'DIRS' to function readfile_ . thanks in advance.

```
export SHELL=$(type -p bash)
function readfile_ {do something}

export -f readfile_ 
ls -d */ | grep -v errlogs |  parallel readfile_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

refer to http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Transfer-environment-variables-and-functions

```
DIRS=/folder/log
export DIRS
ls -d */ | grep -v errlogs |  parallel --env DIRS readfile_
```

Comment: `--env` is only needed if you run your command remotely. The `export` should be plenty otherwise. You can even ignore the `export` if you use version 20140822 and the `env_parallel` function: www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html (under --env)

Comment: @OleTange thank you. just like this: parallel --env _ readfile_. before this line "parallel --record-env" is needed.